# How it's called the java overriding functions after a new

Tags: java, constructor

I'm finding this kind of overriding after a new in java code very often

```
classB body
....
    ClassA a = new ClassA(){
@Override 
public void funcion(){
 atributeClassB = whatever 
   } 
 } ;
....
```

How is it called this kind of constructing ? when is executed the code between brackets ? how this code can have access to a classB attribute ?

in fact if i only know how this way of working is called i can document myselve in google but without a key name i couldn't find it.

the code where i've found it is this [here](http://gitorious.org/pdlib/pd-for-android/blobs/9463a5dd0daadb4ccd94507fd9e7a1ab685d2689/PdTest/src/org/puredata/android/test/PdTest.java) on line 151

Comment: This a popular concept in java, You could find it by a little search in web, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an anonymous local derived class (or "anonymous inner class", though there's a difference between just being "inner" and being *local* [all local classes are inner; not all inner classes are local; more below]). The code within the curly braces forms part of the class definition of the anonymous class.

This

```
ClassA a = new ClassA(){@Override public void funcion(){ atributeClassB = whatever } } ;
```

...is effectively equivalent to this:

```
ClassA a = new SubClassA();
```

...where `SubClassA` is defined within the containing class:

```
class SubClassA extends ClassA {
    @Override public void funcion(){ atributeClassB = whatever }
}
```

...although there's a bit more to it than that because the anonymous class in your example is defined within a method (that's the "local" vs. "inner" thing), [more in the various sections starting here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Answer (score 1):

That's an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct.  I just want to add that the `@Override` annotation means exactly the same thing here as it would in an ordinary method declaration.  It is saying that the method is overriding a method declared in a superclass or (Java 6 and later) implementing a method declared in an interface or abstract superclass.